# CXF and authorization

Tags: java, authorization, cxf, ws-security

I'm using Apache CXF and I'm looking for resources on how to implement authorization for web services. I've found how to implement authentication (using WSS4J) so that I can have dual authentication using X.509 certificates.

I would like to introduce a mechanism of roles so that I can specify for each client, to which role(s) it is associated, and for each role to specify which web methods are allowed to be called.

Is it possible with CXF?
I've looked on the web but I can't find any material on this subject.

Thanks

Comment: Old post, but have you looked at annotations such as javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed from jsr250-api?